# Como puedo guardar el resultado de una consulta con SELECT en una columna especifica

Tags: c#, sql-server

A lo que voy es que yo quiero guardar el resultado que me salga de esta consulta

```
SELECT Nombre FROM Usuario WHERE Nombre = '"datoss.Nombre"'"
```

en la variable usu.
He probado con ese codigo pero al iniciar sesion me da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago la consulta en Sql Server funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Deberias colocar el codigo y no imagenes. Que error te da? coloca la excepcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A veces los textbox.Text no cogeen correctamente solo el texto prueba lo siguiente:

```
datosq.Usuario1 = usuariobox.Text.Trim();
datosq.Contraseña = contrausuario.Text.Trim();
```

PD: añade mejor el código que las capturas, así facilitas trabajar con el.

De todos modos yo haría algo mas fácil para acceder al usuario y contraseña en el mismo evento click del button guardando en un string el usuario y contraseña mediante un dataReader y comparandolo con el texto de los textBox

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tratare de hacer eso de lo que me has dicho.  Una cosa mas: Ese dataReader lo inserto como tipo de Dato y  se lo asigno a una variable?

Comment: Nada! Yo lo haría así si, y luego comparas la variable directamente con el texto del textbox